# Problem inserting a .eps figure after converted it from a .png using Inkscape

Tags: floats, subfloats, eps, png, epstopdf

I have a large graph that I have saved in .eps. However, my result text turns my PC slow when reading these big graphs. My CPU usage on the pdf reader process goes to 20% every time my screen hits these graphs. The result text pdf is very large in size too. This problem occurred generating the graph as eps and png.

This way, I've generated the graph again in png and converted it back to .eps using Inkscape, resulting in a small image. But now, when I try to include this new .eps I receive the error "!File ended while scanning use of @subfloat."

Converting the eps to pdf, using the epstopdf package works. But I would like to know the reason my converted eps does not work as well. I am assuming that .eps has a better resolution than this pdf. Am I right?

Example:

```
\usepackage{epsfig,subfigure,amstext}

\begin{document}
    \begin{figure*}[h]
    \centering
         \subfigure[London]{
                \label{fig:dist1}
                \includegraphics[width=.4\textwidth]
                    {graphs/distLA.eps}%
         \subfigure[Los Angeles]{
                \label{fig:dist2}
                \includegraphics[width=.4\textwidth]
                    {graphs/distLondon.eps}%        
         \caption{The distance distribution between the sequential check-in region center and POI in two cities.}
         \label{fig:dist}
    \end{figure*}
\end{document}
```

[Link to the large figure](https://easyupload.io/bip4il)

[Link to the converted one](https://easyupload.io/nn0s1q)

Comment: an eps created from a png can not have a better resolution than the png (and probably is simply a small wrapper around it).

Comment: But I can assume it is better than the pdf generated by the epstopdf?

Comment: no. Beside this: as you seem to use pdflatex, the eps will in any case be converted to pdf.

Comment: I wasn't using the pdflatex. I have tried it as a solution. First I was using the epsfig package. In your opinion which is better: the pdf generated by pdflatex, or the eps converted from png using Inkscape?

Comment: Don't use the epsfig package, use the graphicx package. If pdflatex ÷ the original eps gives a good pdf use this.

Comment: Thank you @UlrikeFischer. I will follow your advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have encountered the error. Actually the problem wasn't the figures. It was missing a '}' after the figure name in the code.

But I would like to know which format would better to me in quality.